# Download pdf from link using selenium without openning browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to download the pdf from without openning browser. I used requst code but not able to download as pdf is rendered. Hence i try selenium code to perform but didn't get sucess.

```
download_dir = "C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\NewFolder\\"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}],  # Disable Chrome's PDF Viewer
           "download.default_directory": download_dir,
           "download.prompt_for_download": False,
           "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
           "download.open_pdf_in_system_reader": False,
          }
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)
service = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get(link)
```

Please help me out to solve this

Comment: do you mean [headless mode](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/#after)?

Comment: yes exactly!!!!

Comment: I realize that I was one of the persons to ask you try selenium, but if are just going to open webdriver, download and close page, there is another easier way using requests-html. I will add the code in previous question.

Comment: 'options.headless = True' will get for headless but how to perform download programatically

Comment: You need add [wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) for pdf to first load then you need to add this code -> `driver.execute_script("window.addEventListener('load',function({saveDocument();})")`. This will by default download in your Downloads folder unless your changes work

Comment: @DanielSabrel can you pls at leat help me to write the code for download the pdf using selenium , bcz i am not able to achive it

Comment: if above line didn't work try this, `driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("download").click()')`

Comment: it is failing with above too

Comment: can you remove headless, and see what browser is loading?

Comment: i have removed it already, it is not downloading

Comment: I think the problem here is that pdf is in different frame. Normally, `driver.switch_to.frame(frame_element)` should have solved it, but it is not working for this right now. I am looking into it.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check if it works for all urls you have.

Comment: thanks @DanielSabrel it is working for all now.  can you pls remove url link from you comment for safer side

Comment: Actually, I haven't commented the url, just used in the code, which doesn't show in backlinks. I will still remove them. BTW you have mentioned your url in the post instead of using in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was being in different frame as I mentioned. Add this after initializing driver.

```
...
import time
...

urls = ['url1', 'url2']
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    iframe = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe')))   # there is hidden frame for no-script
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    time.sleep()
    download_btn = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#download')))
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', download_btn)
time.sleep(5)   # waiting to download before closing
```

If TimeoutException shows up, increase wait time from 10,